# using overloaded operator = for copying a vector of objects

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I try to copy the vector comanda to the vector comenzi :

```
 public :
        Ospatar(char nume[30],Comanda * comanda,int nrcom,char sex,int varst)
        {
            strcpy(Nume,nume);

            comenzi=new Comanda[sizeof(comanda)];
            for(int i=0;i<sizeof(comanda);i++)
            {
                comenzi[i]=comanda[i];

            }
            cout<<endl;

            nrComenzi=nrcom;
            gen=sex;
            varsta=varst;

        }
```

And here is the overloaded operator from Class Comanda :

```
Comanda& operator=(Comanda  c)
    {
        Prod.set_denProd(c.Prod.get_denProd());

        Num=c.Num;
        nrPortii=c.nrPortii;
        date.zi=c.date.zi;
        date.luna=c.date.luna;
        date.an=c.date.an;

    }
```

the first two elements of vector comanda are well transfered to vector comenzi but after that i get some random numbers ...

Comment: sizeof(comanda) doesn't give you the correct size

Comment: I think you need to use nrcom instead

Comment: The correct overloading of ``operator=`` is ``T& operator=(const T& t)``

Comment: Consider `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @nefas has a point; not taking reference means that a copy constructor will also be called, something you probably don't want.

Comment: @NickyC If she's in my college, year 1, she probably doesn't really have that option

Comment: @PaulStelian,thank you for your answear,but it still doesn't work,same problem

Comment: and yes,I am year 1

Comment: @Oana Either way this code doesn't look that safe for C++ code... I think my Facebook profile is visible on my account here, maybe you can contact me separatel

Comment: @Oana Hint: `sizeof(comanda)` doesn't do what you think it does. I'll reopen your question, but please leave us with a [MCVE]. Also you should inspect your program with the debugger stepping through line by line and watch the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use std::vertor -- this is the right way to do that in C++. But assuming that you're not allowed to use standard library:

First your Comanda::operator= should take argument via reference (preferably reference to const):

```
Comanda& operator=(const Comanda& c)
```

Then, sizeof(comanda) returns size of pointer to Comanda, not number of elements in the array. You generally have to pass the size of the array in separate argument (I guess `nrcom` is the one).

So:

```
comenzi = new Comanda[nrcom];
for (int i=0; i<nrcom; i++)
```

etc...

You'll of course need to clean the code more (what's that strcpy thing), and last but not least don't forget to add delete [] for your allocated data.